# Задача "Найти самую длинную серию чисел в стобце двухмерного массива". Я написал код, но работает он не правильно

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> arr = {{1,2,5,6,2}, {1,5,5,6,6}, {1,4,5,6,1}, {1,5,6,1,5}};

    int prevMaxSeries{ 0 };
    int series{ 0 };
    int maxSeries{ 0 };
    int indexColumn{ -1 };
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j - 1][i] == arr[j][i])
            {
                series++;
            }
            else
            {
                maxSeries = series > maxSeries ? series : maxSeries; 
                series = 0;
            }
        }
       maxSeries = series > maxSeries ? series : maxSeries;

        if (maxSeries > prevMaxSeries)
        {
            indexColumn = j;
            prevMaxSeries = maxSeries;
        }
        maxSeries = 0;
        cout << arr[j][i];
    }


}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о максимальной серии в одном столбце, то вы забыли между столбцами инициализировать счетчик. Поскольку у вас начинается просмотр столбца со второго элемента, то начальное значение должно быть 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
    series = 1; // инициализировать счетчик серии перед новым столбцом
    for (j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
    {
```

Ещё ошибка, на которую указал MBo - `arr.size()` неправильно использовать во внешнем цикле. Внешний цикл идет по столбцам, а `arr.size()` - это количество строк. Во внешнем цикле должно быть `i<arr[0].size()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].size(); i++)
{
```

Ещё одна ошибка - вывод в поток элемента массива после окончания цикла. Цикл   по строкам завершился, `j == arr.size()` и `arr[j][i];` - выход за пределы массива

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].size(); i++)
{
    series = 1; // инициализировать счетчик серии перед новым столбцом
    for (j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++) // выход из цикла при j == arr.size()
    {
    }
    cout << arr[j][i]; // выход за пределы массива, т.к. j == arr.size()
}
```

И ещё непонятен смысл переменной `prevMaxSeries` - она просто не нужна. Есть размер текущей серии `series` и есть сохранение максимальной серии `maxSeries` - всё, этого достаточно.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].size(); i++)
{
    series = 0;
    for (j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
    {
        ....
    }
    maxSeries = series > maxSeries ? series : maxSeries;
}
```

Если исправите все ошибки - работает.

Comment: Ещё arr.size неправильно использовать во внешнем цикле

Comment: Добавил обнуление ничего не работает*(